# Make item unable to be picked up and despawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to:

1: Make an item unable to be picked up.

2: Make an item unable to despawn.

I want to put items on the ground that are for decoration that nobody can pick up.

EDIT: Minecraft 1.14.4

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the NBT for item entities has a field for how long it takes to despawn and for how long it can't be picked up.

```
/summon item <X> <Y> <Z> {Item:{id:"<type of item>",Count:<number of items>},PickupDelay:32767,Age:-32768}
```

Comment: /summon Item <X> <Y> <Z>  worked but than the rest was red. By the way, I am in 1.14.4. Any ideas?

Comment: @SillyEar7 You need to specify an item to summon, replacing the `...`. Example, to summon a piece of stone that can't be picked up or despawn, `/summon Item <X> <Y> <Z> {Item:{id:stone},PickupDelay:32767,Age:-32768}`

Comment: Sorry that I didn't see that. By the way, is there a way for me to use items like brown dye with it? I tried but didn't see it. I'm on Java Edition, so for it is the ID different than brown_dye?

Comment: @SillyEar7 `brown_dye` appears to be the correct ID for Brown Dye, don't know why that wouldn't work.

Comment: The command doesn't work, because `Item` in `/summon Item` can't be capitalited and you need to specify the `Count` within the `Item` tag. The fixed command looks like this: `/summon item <X> <Y> <Z> {Item:{id:"<type of item>",Count:1b},PickupDelay:32767,Age:-32768}`. If you for example want to summon brown dye where you currently stand, then you can use this command: `/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:brown_dye",Count:1b},PickupDelay:32767,Age:-32768}`

Comment: @bearb001 Fixed. It's somewhat ironic that I post an incorrect answer after having spent so much effort correcting and updating other answers.

Comment: If you write the `id` in the `Item` tag as a string, then the namespace is required, too. While `/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:brown_dye,Count:1b},PickupDelay:32767,Age:-32768}` will work, `/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"brown_dye",Count:1b},PickupDelay:32767,Age:-32768}` won't. I recommend changing this part (`id:"<type of item>"`) to something like this: `id:"minecraft:<type of item>"`, or `id:"<namespace>:<type of item>"`

Comment: @bearb001 It's working for me without any namespace.

Comment: I tested it again now and it did work, this is weird, I could swear I tried this exact thing a few days ago (in a different situation). And I even tested the command before sending it and it didn't work. I guess I got confused and thought I tested that command while actually testing something else, or something like that. Edit: I went through my recent commands and found that I apparently forgot the `Count` tag when I tested the command without the namespace.

Comment: @SillyEar7 This answer has now been corrected.